# strapi and react form not adding data to the admin

Tags: reactjs, strapi

previous issue

[building a rating app using strapi and react throws errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74490898/building-a-rating-app-using-strapi-and-react-throws-errors) is solved.

But, the records are not getting added to the admin.

can anyone help on this?

This is the code to add and read reviews from strapi admin,

```
function App() {
    const stars = Array(5).fill(0);
    const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = React.useState(0);
    const [hoverValue, setHoverValue] = React.useState(undefined);

    const handleClick = (value) => {
        setCurrentValue(value);
    };

    const handleMouseOver = (value) => {
        setHoverValue(value);
    };

    const [review, setReview] = useState({});
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await api.readReviews();
            //console.log(result.data);
            setReviews(result.data.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    const createReview = async () => {
        try {
            //console.log(review);
            const data = await api.createReview(review);
            setReview([...reviews, data]);
        } catch (error) {
            //console.log(error);
        }
    };
    let [reviewCount, setreviewCount] = useState([]);
    const setCountFxn = (no) => {
        setReview(no);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <form>
                <div style={styles.container}>
                    <h2>RATE OUR SERVICE</h2>

                    <div style={styles.stars}>
                        {stars.map((_, index) => {
                            return (
                                <FaStar
                                    key={index}
                                    size={24}
                                    style={{
                                        marginRight: 10,
                                        cursor: 'pointer',
                                    }}
                                    color={(hoverValue || currentValue) > index ? colors.orange : colors.grey}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        setReview({ ...review, Rating: index + 1 });
                                    }}
                                    onMouseOver={() => handleMouseOver(index + 1)}
                                />
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            placeholder='input your name'
                            required
                            style={styles.input}
                            value={review.Name}
                            onChange={(e) => setReview({ ...review, Name: e.target.value })}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <textarea
                        placeholder="what's your feedback"
                        required
                        style={styles.textarea}
                        value={review.review}
                        onChange={(e) => setReview({ ...review, review: e.target.value })}
                    />
                    <button type='submit' style={styles.button} className='btn btn-primary' onClick={createReview}>
                        submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <section id='reviews'>
                <div className='reviews-heading'>
                    <span>REVIEWS FROM CUSTOMERS</span>
                </div>

                <div className='container'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        {reviews.map((review, i) => (
                            <div key={review.id} className='col-md-6'>
                                <div className='reviews-box'>
                                    <div className='box-top'>
                                        <div className='profile'>
                                            <div className='name-user'>
                                                <strong>{review.attributes.Title}</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div style={styles.stars}>
                                            {Array.from({ length: review.attributes.Rating }).map((i) => (
                                                <FaStar key={i} size={18} color={colors.orange} />
                                            ))}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className='client-comment'>{review.attributes.Body}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
    );
}


export default App;
```

The form gets submitted and reloads after submit, but the record does not get added to strapi admin. I've set the roles of the data to public.

thanks
Nabi

Comment: A couple of thoughts:
1. Did you confirm you have permissions to the endpoint `api.createReview`? 
2. Can you log the `data` after this line: `const data = await api.createReview(review);`
What I'd suggest is use Postman to test your endpoint. Also check your Strapi console, if you hit the endpoint, you should see something there.

Comment: 1. how do i confirm i have permission?, 2. i've added the log but nothing is showing when submitting. I tried adding a record in postman but get this error:"data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 400,
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Missing \"data\" payload in the request body",
        "details": {}
    }

Comment: do I need to add a token of any sort?

Comment: From that error, seems that the object you're sending is missing some properties. Can you log that object, before sending it?

Comment: For the permissions, you can check them in Settings/Roles. If you should access to the data without login, check the Public role and confirm that your schema (Review, I guess)  has permission to `CREATE and UPDATE`. If your data needs to be accessed by an authenticated user, just check the other role, and confirm it have those permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive figured it out!
The values of the form were named wrong. "Name" should be "Title" and "review" should be "Body".  It now adds the data to the strapi admin.

Answer (score 0):

You need a very specific structure to create a new entry with strapi. I assume your payload looks like this:

```js
{
  name: 'xyz',
  rating: 5
}
```

Correct would be:

```js
{
  data: {
    name: 'xyz',
    rating: 5
  }
}
```

[Strapi Docs - Creating an entry](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest-api.html#create-an-entry)

Comment: How would I add the entry through the code in the createReview function? Could you send an example using my code?

Comment: Well, if the structure really is like that (only you know that, just log your data), you can do `const data = await api.createReview({data: review})`